# Could someone please share what they know about, or references on, a computer running a government (ethical implications etc) in a work of sci-fi?

Tags: science-based, scientific-development, science-fiction

I'm looking for any work that looks at a computer in some future or alien civilization which is designed to govern its civilization or sectors of it at the administrative level.

All references appreciated and especially those that have potential in actual science ! Surely some or other futurist has predicted such machines... ,)

In particular, what are the possible benefits of turning administration over to a computer, and what are the drawbacks. As well, how advanced would the system have to be? Could you run a society with a general purpose computer system such as we have today, or would the society need a more advanced sort of system, such as a strong AI, neural network, quantum computer or something else?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off-topic. I'm not entirely sure it's the right close reason as there is some basis of worldbuilding here, but I'm sure someone can correct me if I'm wrong...

Comment: You can't envisage how a computer that runs an entire government in a parellel world isn't related to world building...? I guess you don't have an appreciation for the pillars of a society, namely social institutions, the government being one of them... but that's ok.

Comment: That's the element of worldbuilding in this question. I appreciate that there is worldbuilding here, but I think this question needs to be rewritten before it's a good format for this site. Closing is the tool to do that: a closed question can still be edited, and closing is primarily to ensure that answerers don't get confused about question details and blame you for it :) When the question is in a good format, it can (and many do) get reopened.

Comment: I can't put my finger on it but I am pretty sure that a work of *Stanislav Lem* covered the topic.

Comment: I think the problem could be that it's asking for references. It's usually not a type of question well liked on Stack exchange because most people can answer with just the name of a book.

Comment: Thanks, Ghanima, for answering the perfectly clear and intelligible question. I'll check it out!! :)

Comment: Actually I edited the question while you posted this one and prior to reading your first comment. Nontheless, I think it follows the tenor of most any other question that I've seen here, but maybe your experiences of questions is different. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Vincent, there is no problem, that's the point. It's not asking for references but what people know about (or as an alternative references)... not sure how you read around that part of the question though, but no biggy.

Comment: I loaded your edit while I wrote my comment just in case it changed the question so I wouldn't have t post it. It didn't. So I posted it anyway. Vincent has laid his finger on it; you're asking for works on this topic which leads to a non-objectively answerable question. These don't fit well on StackExchange.

Comment: Like I said, ArtofCode, you can ignore the question if you like, that's okay, but don't expect others to as well. Best of luck in the future, and thanks again anyways.

Comment: Yes, but it's not really fair, though. I mean... You've asked an open-ended question that doesn't really have a "best" answer, or even a "single" answer. You've chosen as "correct" someone who gave you a mere two references. Are they the BEST references ever? [Certainly not.](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MasterComputer) Will I get any points for linking you to that? Doubtful. Do I feel robbed? Definitely.

Comment: @JustinChapman I'm *ignoring the question* because it shouldn't be here: as I have said, this type of question doesn't fit the StackExchange format thus I will not answer it. This is about to be closed (only needs one more vote) - if you can change it to fit format please do.

Comment: I added the last close vote here. For the record, the previous four were for "not about worldbuilding" (the on-hold/closed annotation unfortunately does not make that particularly clear). I agree with the previous comments, this question has two main problems: (1) it asks for an unbounded set of answers, which the SE Q&A format handles very poorly, and (2) it asks for merely references, rather than how to solve a given problem. Please review http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic as well as http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/asking. To discuss the issue, post on [meta].

Comment: Guys, I already got my answer. I understand, you want the question to be something it's not. It was very clear. Do you know any such fictional scenario where a computer is made to run a government. That's it. The question was answered and I was happy with the way the person answered it. I also left open the possibility of references, but that was parenthetical. Again, please review the question rules, versus "help." I don't need "help" asking a question. I got my answer. As for those of you who don't like my attitude, life goes on. Thanks ,)

Comment: Asked a question NOT about world-building. Asked a question about sci-fi references. You haven't mentioned anything about any "world" you want "built". Your question specifically states "in a work of sci-fi" at the end, meaning that you don't want people's PERSONAL thoughts about your potential world. You want existing examples from established authors. Go join a book club. Also "they"? I think you'll find that a vote from five different users of the site closed your question. There's no central authority that deems you worthy, unlike your computer-government.

Comment: Well hello there, Ayelis. It would appear that you're here for some schooling? That's perfect, schooling is what I do! The question is about one of the most fundamental sociological institutions of humanity and therefore any literal sense of the word world as we know it. If you can't  connect the dots, a "world" of the sort I was speaking is one inhabited by intelligent, social life... Hence "government." Unless you were under the impression that I were asking about plant life? Nice try, though! Best of luck with reading, book clubs aside.

Comment: Congratulations!!! based off the votes of the people this is the least liked question on the world building stack exchange.

Comment: Thanks, I think it goes to show that people often react to their expectations, emotions, attitudes, moods and the like, and are as well frequently influenced by what they (again) perceive as the group's overall feeling or response. If you look at the question among any number of others, you'll see that it's perfectly acculturated and indeed got its answers as it should have. :)

Comment: Have you looked at _The Dosadi Experiment_? It may be useful to you, as I recall Dosadi is run by some sort of A.I.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be exactly what you're looking for but is very closely related.

The movie *WarGames* involves a Cold War-era US military computer designed to make all strategical decisions by predicting all possible outcomes. The computer essentially runs their military command and inevitably, its decisions become important ethical decisions when it begins planning to wage nuclear war with Russia.

Another example (sort of) is the book *A Wrinkle In Time*. Can't provide a ton of detail on this one so I'll leave this here: [Wikipedia article](http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Wrinkle_in_Time)

Comment: I'll definitely look into the Wiki page! The WarGames is great, too! Thank you!! :)

Answer (score 3):

I see another answer is already accepted but I feel like throwing in my two cents anyway.

For references, I know the final story in Asimov's *I, Robot* collection dealt with computers making important economic decisions, and gently "shaking the boat" by fudging some numbers so that people who disagreed with them would be removed from power. (It sounds ominous when I put it that way. It wasn't like that in the book.) He didn't go into the specifics of technology, but they were implied to be a half-dozen or so supercomputers scattered around the world, and ran on the same magic positronic brains as the rest of Asimov's robots.

Another Asimov story, [*The Last Question*](http://www.multivax.com/last_question.html), had an AI running the entire universe after all the humans populating every galaxy were put into a *Matrix*-like cryostasis so that they would never die. (Geez, were all of his stories so dark and I never noticed?) This one was even more handwavy-magic than the positronic brains. He even says that it cannot be comprehended by mere humans.

On a lighter note, the excellent webcomic [Schlock Mercenary](http://www.schlockmercenary.com) has had many AI characters in government positions. They are basically depicted as really smart people, and perform all the functions of the government. They run on magic quantum ternary matrices, but as far as I know neither quantum nor ternary have any advantages for AI. (My personal opinion is that the randomness of quantum mechanics could mirror the chaotic nature of neurochemicals, but I have no idea what I'm talking about so ignore me.)

To answer your actual question, the benefits and drawbacks depend heavily on what kind of computer, how advanced, etc. If it's basically a mind like ours in a metal shell, but faster, it could probably run all the government's functions and handle the bureaucracy more efficiently than any group of people ever could. The biggest danger would be it getting bored and going off to do something else. Such minds are obviously way beyond our current technology, and it's anybody's guess what technology would be required.

On the other hand, if it's just making economic decisions (production, distribution, etc.) a modern computer could probably handle it. We already have supercomputers trading stocks thousands of times per second. With the right algorithms, it could run the military as well: consider that computer games have enemy AI, and these days it's sometimes even smart. Evolutionary algorithms and machine learning could overhaul our tactics, without the need for any technology beyond what we have today. But such "decision" machines are not something I would trust to handle lawmaking, policing, judging, or any other government functions that require some understanding of impacts on human lives.

Comment: Knave, thank you very much for your answer. The reason I accepted the other answer was to show the people with a bad attitude that stubbornness wouldn't win here. I did genuinely appreciate the asnwer and am looking into Amazon deals on both, as I will also look into your references. So obviously I liked the answer as well. In short, thank you for taking your time to share your knowledge, versus ignoring my question because "it's a "wrong" question..." :) Much appreciated!!

Comment: As long as we're talking Asimov, don't forget about Multivac and [*Franchise*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franchise_(short_story)).

Answer (score 1):

*The Moon is a Harsh Mistress* contains elements of the main robot (HOLMES IV or Mike) forming the government of the moon during a revolt. I'm not sure the specifics or such like that, it's been a while since I read the novel. It is written by Robert Heinlein.

Comment: Heinlein is one example, but your answer could be improved if you were to add more detail. Even if you haven't read the book in a while, there are lots of Internet sites to brush up on the details. Since the question is very vague, an answer with detail might help the author of the question focus their thinking more.